# Центрирование div по центру родительского div

Tags: css, html

Вопрос избитый, но справиться не могу.
Есть внешний div c внутренним дивом и картинкой во всю ширину

Не могу отцентрировать текст поверх картинки

```
<div class="one">
  <div class="two">Text</div>
  <img class="full" src="https://pp.vk.me/c630828/v630828919/5293e/hThcyFPuX24.jpg">    
</div>
```

css

```
.one {
  background-color: #ccc;

}
.two {
  width: 40%;
  height: 40%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.full {
  width:100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Лучше приложите полный код, чтобы желающие помочь могли сразу скопировать себе и подправить, а не писать самим.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Применяем **абсолютное позиционирование+margin:auto;**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.one {
  background-color: #ccc;
  position: relative;
}
.two {
  width: 40%;
  height: 40%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background: #ccc;
}
.full {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <div class="two">Text</div>
  <img class="full" src="https://pp.vk.me/c630828/v630828919/5293e/hThcyFPuX24.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо, помогло

Answer (score 1):

Можно через свойство flex,

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.one {
  display: flex; 
  height: 300px;
  background:url(https://pp.vk.me/c630828/v630828919/5293e/hThcyFPuX24.jpg) no-repeat center;
  background-size: contain;
}
.two {
  margin: auto;
  background: red; 
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <div class="two">Text</div>
</div>
```